# Facebook Friend Picker Sample not working Out-of-the-box IOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can anyone lead me to why the Facebook Friend Picker Sample project doesn't work right out of the box? It asks me for permissions, but when I try to "Find Friends", an empty table view appears as opposed to my entire friend list. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6):

As of 4/30/2014, you can only get friends who also use the same app, and you must request the user_friends permission for that.

See more here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids

Comment: so is there no way to get a list of all friends?? seems like a step back

Comment: It's actually better for the people using the service... Apps don't need access to the friend list.   Game categorized apps can use the new Invitable Friends api to invite friends to the game.

Comment: This should be the correct answer please mark it as such

Comment: The list of friends is no longer part of the default list of permissions and only returns the friends using the app. See the section above on user IDs and friends to learn more about how IDs and friends are changing.

Comment: Strangely, I only saw this happen yesterday in my app. I'm shocked that even Facebook's own example is outdated. I know you can't get the friends by default, but to clarify, there's no permission I can ask to see their friends unless they're also using my app?

Comment: Correct.  No more access to full friends list.  It's a huge win for user privacy that developers have to deal with.

Comment: I sure wish they'd update their tutorial and examples!

Answer (score 0):

For Open Graph API 2.0 onwards, use FBTaggableFriendPickerViewController instead.
This will require you to set permissions in the Open Graph Object on the Facebook App Settings.

The id that is returned is encrypted and I'm not sure if that is temporary or permanent. I would think it's the former.